# Error while trying to run Ubuntu installed on a pen-drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, busybox, xhci-hcd

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on my pen-drive (32 GB USB 3.0), using [this installation procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLYBXOVn6ow). When I try to boot from that pen-drive, the selection screen appears. I select the normal Ubuntu to boot, then I get the following error message:

```
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
usb 2-7: hub failed to enable device, error -62
usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -62
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args(cat/proc/cmdline)
 -Check rootdelay=( did system wait long enough?)
 -Check root=(did systemwait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; Is /dev)
ALERT! UUID=-------------------------- does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.
(initramfs)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JckuM.jpg)

I also tried installing Ubuntu gnome 15.10, 14.04 AMD Ubuntu unity 15.10 and still got the same error. I tried on a different laptop and am still getting the same error.
Installing and running Ubuntu on a pen-drive is my only option as my laptop has only SSD and I can't dual boot it with windows.

Comment: Try a different pen-drive. Don't trust every Youtube guru. AskUbuntu and UbuntuForums are the most appropriate places for adequate help.

Answer (score 0):

In your windows download the software Rufus. Download your desired Ubuntu  iso. Then insert your pendrive and use Rufus to create the bootable usb. Have a good luck.

Comment: I did that, it's for creating a live usb and installing ubuntu from that usb. I'm installing ubuntu in a different pen drive and getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Honestly I don't think it is possible to actually install Ubuntu on pendrive. You can only make a live usb. And there should be no problem working from a live usb. If you create casper partition you can also store data permanently, install apps and do updates. The only thing you will not be able to do is upgrade. And using a 32 GB pendrive you are all set to go.

Comment: How do I do that casper partition thing? I lose my data every time I boot from my live usb.

Comment: See http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/ This way if you use a 32 GB pendrive you have minimum 4GB of system partition and another 28 GB of file storage space. Good luck.